# Not able to transform array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert this array of objects into a different format:

```
let data = [
    { 
        Dimension_ID: 1,
        A1: 'N'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 2,
        A1: 'N'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 3,
        A1: 'N'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 917,
        A1: 'P'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 918,
        A1: 'P'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 919,
        A1: 'P'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 1,
        B1: 'Q'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 2,
        B1: 'Q'
    }, {
        Dimension_ID: 3,
        B1: 'Q'
    }
];
```

I want to create a new object like this:

```
let params = [];

params['filterValues'] =  { A1: [ 'N', 'P' ],B1: [ 'Q' ] };
```

Here is the JavaScript code I'm trying to use.

```
  if(params.filterValues != undefined){
                    params.dimensionIds2 = [];
                        for (var key in params.filterValues) {
                            if(params.filterValues[key].length > 0)
                            params.filterValues[key].map((value)=>{
                                let filterData = data.filter(item => item[key] == value);
                                filterData.map((filterItem)=>{
                                    console.log(key,value,filterItem.Dimension_ID);
                                    //params.dimensionIds2[key][value].push(filterItem.Dimension_ID)   
                                })

                            })

                          }
                    }
```

I can console.log values in loop like this:

- A1 N 1
- A1 N 2
- A1 N 3
- A1 P 917
- A1 P 918
- A1 P 919
- B1 Q 1
- B1 Q 2
- B1 Q 3

I want to use this data something like:

data['A1']['N'] = [1,2,3]

data['A1']['P'] = [917,918,919]

data['B1']['Q'] = [1,2,3]

I also tried using this code:

```
params.dimensionIds2[key][value].push(filterItem.Dimension_ID)
```

Comment: Note that `data` should be object not array. Arrays only have numeric indexing

Comment: Also provide some sample data to make this a runnable  [mcve]

Comment: I have updated the question with some input data.

Comment: @JonathanRys these are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another nested `Array#reduce()` approach. Note you want `params` and the result to be objects not arrays in order to use string values for keys

```js
let params = {};
let data = [{ Dimension_ID: 1,A1: 'N'},{ Dimension_ID: 2,A1: 'N'},{ Dimension_ID: 3,A1: 'N'},
{ Dimension_ID: 917,A1: 'P'},{ Dimension_ID: 918,A1: 'P'},{ Dimension_ID: 919,A1: 'P'},
{ Dimension_ID: 1,B1: 'Q'},{ Dimension_ID: 2,B1: 'Q'},{ Dimension_ID: 3,B1: 'Q'},];
params['filterValues'] =  { A1: [ 'N', 'P' ],B1: [ 'Q' ] };

let res = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  return Object.entries(params['filterValues']).reduce((a,[k, arr]) => {
    a[k] = a[k] || {}
    return arr.reduce((a,v) => {
      const o = a[k][v] = a[k][v] || [];
      c[k] && c[k] === v && o.push(c.Dimension_ID)
      return a
    },a);    
  },a);  
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to organize your data.

```js
let data = [
    {Dimension_ID: 1, A1: 'N'},
    {Dimension_ID: 2, A1: 'N'},
    {Dimension_ID: 3, A1: 'N'},
    {Dimension_ID: 917, A1: 'P'},
    {Dimension_ID: 918, A1: 'P'},
    {Dimension_ID: 919, A1: 'P'},
    {Dimension_ID: 1, B1: 'Q'},
    {Dimension_ID: 2, B1: 'Q'},
    {Dimension_ID: 3, B1: 'Q'},];

const params = {A1: ['N', 'P'], B1: ['Q']};

const organize = (data, params) =>

    Object.keys(params).reduce((acc, val) => {

        acc[val] = params[val].reduce((a, v) => {
            
            a[v] = data
                      .filter((value) => value[val] === v)
                      .map(value => value.Dimension_ID);
            
            return a;
        }, {});

        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(organize(data, params));
```